# Rename Apollo Federation's OpenTelemetry traces based on operation name (named queries)

Tags: monitoring, apollo, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, apollo-federation

I have a federated Apollo Graph (using `ApolloGateway`) and a bunch of subgraph microservices. I’ve set them up to do distributed tracing via OpenTelemetry.

Now, they do produce a bunch of traces that I can see in my backend (Elastic APM). However, they are all named `graphql.execute`, `graphql.parse`, etc. It is not easy to look for a specific mutation or query to monitor.
What I want to do instead is to take the operation name from the named queries like:

```
query HeroNameAndFriends {
  hero {
    name
    friends {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

and rename the entire trace to `HeroNameAndFriends`.

- Is that an acceptable, recommended thing to do?
- How would I achieve that?
- Do subgraphs have access to the name of the named queries? Can I start small from one of the microservices or do I have to modify the Gateway?

Thank you!